# Visual Studio 2013 not handling Doxygen multi-line comments correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, documentation, doxygen, atomineer

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (C++) with the Atomineer Utils add-in.

Coming from a Java background, I was interested in the Doxygen style of documentation, so I configured Atomineer to use the `Doxygen (Javadoc)` style, which looks like this basically:

```
/**
 * @brief adds two numbers together
 */
void add(int x, int y);
```

However, let's say I want to start a multi-line comment. Coming from IntelliJ IDEA, I assumed this would work:

```
/**
```

<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
/**
 *
```

or better yet:

```
/**
```

<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
/**
 *
 */
```

In reality, this produces the strangest results:

```
/**

# autocompletes to

/**/
```

<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
/**
/* /
```

Hopefully you can understand how unhelpful that sort of autocomplete behavior is.

On top of that, if you manage to get a complete Doxygen comment on, extending that comment only works if (from my observations):

- You aren't selecting the beginning of the comment (`/**`)
- You are selecting after the asterisk before hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, and not the space that automatically generates after it: (`|` represents the cursor)

  ```
  /**
   *|
   */
  ```

  then hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> would work, but not

  ```
  /**
   * |
   */
  ```
- *OR* you type something on that line and hit enter

Now on to how I would prefer to solve the problem: **to somehow fix the multi-line comment generation and automatic extension to be similar to what I expect.**

However, if you guys are certain that that kind of solution does not exist, then I am aware that Atomineer generates documentation automatically if I type `///` (but why not `/**`!?) and I can use that instead as a sort of work-around.

What I have tried so far:

- Disabled `Complete Multiline Comments` under Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced (this disables it AND Atomineer's documentation generator)
- Disabled `Generate XML documentation comments for ///` under Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced (We're talking C++ here so obviously this didn't do anything)

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies for the late answer, I didn't spot this question earlier)

The simple work-around would have been to type /// or ctrl+shift+D to generate the comment. However, Atomineer has since been updated, and also now allows you to type /** to generate a comment.